# Combine, minify, and replace references to JS and CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, maven, minify

Is there a solution out there that will combine and minify js and css files, and then replace the references to them in the original html files? I've found a number of solutions that will minify and combine, but none that will replace the references in the original html file. The  Web Minifier Maven plugin from http://mojo.codehaus.org/webminifier-maven-plugin/ does exactly what I want for JS files, but doesn't deal with CSS files. Is there anything that does? Our build process uses Maven, so the solution needs to be either a Maven plugin or a script.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing right now.

Comment: You can give this library a go. I am biased of course ;)  https://nuget.org/packages/RxLoader/

Answer (score 1):

Google Closure Tools provides all of this functionality.

## References

- [Closure Tools Reference](https://developers.google.com/closure/) (includes compiler and HTML templates).
- [Closure Stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/)

The Closure-compiler supports Maven integration.

Comment: Could Closure combine (inline) all related js, css into html, make it a single html file?